# Call a function in a jquery plugin using an argument

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

I've a basic jquery plugin where uses data attributes data-something="thing" to tell the plugin what function run inside of it.

I was using the next to do it:

```
// Plugin definition.
$.fn.plugin = function( options ) {
    // Iterate and reformat each matched element.
    return this.each(function() {
        var func = element.data('something');
        var response = plugin[func]($(this));
    });
};
```

And it works just fine. But i wanted to follow the jquery standars where functions should be called:

```
$.fn.plugin.thing($(this));
```

**So...the question. How to archive that? Is that possible when the same of the function comes in text?**

Thanks!

Comment: `$.fn.plugin['thing'](..);`

Comment: Look here for some standard jquery plugin patterns : http://viget.com/inspire/jquery-plugin-patterns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am interpreting your question correctly, you're looking to be able to use `$.fn.plugin.func` instead of `$.fn.plugin[func]`, where `func` is a variable storing a string that is the method name? If that is the case, I don't think it is possible because JavaScript will be looking for a method named `func` in the `plugin` variable as opposed to the method named after the string contained in the `func` variable.

Comment: Yes, thats what I tough. Thanks!